# Is there any document about O365 API Call limitation?

Tags: office365, office365api

I would like to know the O365 API Call limitation such as the document below.

ex. [Power BI REST API limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950053.aspx).

Is there any document about it?
I hope you will be able to provide the information.

thanks,
masa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST API: 
[Throttling coming to Outlook API and Microsoft Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/)

EWS API: [EWS throttling in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

In Office365, it use throttling policy to limit API calls, it is not like the number of calls per second rule. The documentation are below:

1. [How to: Avoid getting throttled or blocked in SharePoint Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn889829.aspx)
2. [Exchange Online Throttling and Limits FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Matt, I can understand limitation !